# System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocket memory leak?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, websocket, uwp

I try to send images from a webcam with WebSocket.

Here is my test code: even if I never change what I'm sending, the same instance of an ArraySegment (with the same content), memory usage is going sky-high very soon, even more, if I compile to x64.

```
HttpListenerWebSocketContext webSocketContext = await httpListenerContext.AcceptWebSocketAsync(subProtocol: null, receiveBufferSize: 1024, keepAliveInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), internalBuffer: segment);
System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocket webSocket = webSocketContext.WebSocket;
segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(imgData1);
                        while (true)
                        {   
                            await webSocket.SendAsync(segment, WebSocketMessageType.Binary, true, CancellationToken.None);
                            await Task.Delay(20);
                        }
```

Is it a bug, and I have to rewrite everything for e.g. TcpListener? The existing way would be more convenient and my codes are ready for this.

Comment: `while` will not stop for your `await` lines and runs many of them.

Comment: might set up a counter integer and see how many itterations has been sent. Memory might be consumed because you create a response much quicker then send it, and it should be stored somewhere ...

Comment: update: it seems like the issue may not be with the WebSocket. I'm investigating it, please wait.

Comment: Do you solve this issue?